# jQuery and CSS set an absolute div to the center of the screen (detecting screen's resolution)

Tags: jquery, css, position

I  want to create a new layer including a login form (or other features), and I want to display it at center of the screen (depending on the screen's resolution and content).

**This is the code :**

```
  function new_layer() {
    $('#frameContainer, #showbox').show();
    $('#showbox').load('includes/login.php');
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var hei = eval($(window).height()/2 - $('#showbox > *').outerHeight()/2);
        var wid = eval($(window).width()/2 - $('#showbox > *').outerWidth()/2);
        $('#showbox').css({
          top: hei + "px",
          left: wid + "px"
        }).show();
    });

    // ..................
```

At the first time, it does not work, the content of the file `login.php` is centered :( , but when I click outside to hide it, then click again, it works. When I refresh the page, the problem occurs again.

What is the problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? It's not only naughty, it's not even necessary in your code.

Comment: Sr i'm a beginner, and i'm a cautious person, i try to do things safely :)

Comment: If you want to be safe, then [never use `eval` in your code until you're 100% sure you know what you're doing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
var loginDialog = $('#loginDialog');

    $.blockUI();
    var dlgWidth = loginDialog.outerWidth();
    var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();
    var pos = (viewPortWidth - dlgWidth ) / 2;
    loginDialog.css({

        'position', 'absolute',
        'left' :  pos + 'px',
        'z-index' : '1999' //greater than setting for blockUI
    });

});
```

More on [blockUI here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)

Comment: Don't position the `left` and `right` both, or one will override the other and you might get unexpected results.

Comment: @Blazemonger: I must admit. I didn't get what you mean by *`both, or one will override the other`*.

Comment: Normally you'd set `left` and `top`, not `left` and `right`. In your code, setting both is redundant anyway.

Comment: @Blazemonger: oops! You're right, I need not set `right` :). I clearly over-engineered this :P  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS calculations for that:

```
#loginDialog {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px; /* half of the height */
    margin-left: -200px; /* half of the width */
}
```

Comment: I don't think the dialog's height and width are necessarily known in advance.

Comment: @Blazemonger possible.. But it seems to be a regular pre-designed login popup, which is pretty static on most of the websites